# Why syntax like "for value in LinkedList" can reach values in nodes of a linked list (Python)?

Tags: python, linked-list

I found that "for xxx in linked_list" works just as "for xxx in list" in python. In my comprehension linked list has no index and thus nodes can't be reached without node.next. But this code works somehow. So how could this be possible? Why python knows where's the next node is and automatically returns its value (not node itself, but an attribute value stored in the node)

```
   new_list = LinkedList()

   for value in linked_list:

       # do aomething with value of node
```

I found a **iter**() method in LinkedList definition. Is Python calling this method while iterating through the list?

```
class LinkedList:

   def __init__(self):
      self.head = None
    
   def __iter__(self):
       node = self.head
       while node:
           yield node.value
           node = node.next
        
   def __repr__(self):
       return str([v for v in self])

class Node:
   def __init__(self, value):
       self.value = value
       self.next = None
```

Comment: The `LinkedList` class presumably implements the iteration protocol by providing a `__next__()` method.

Comment: If you want to know why, it would help to show the definition of `LinkedList` and `Node`.  Make a [mcve].

Comment: That, or it provides `__getitem__` but not `__iter__`, and Python is falling back to `__getitem__`-based iteration, which is extremely inefficient for a linked list.

Comment: you would have to check source code of `LinkedList` to see how it work.

Comment: Thanks! I just posted the definition of Node and LinkedList, is that __iter__() method called while iterating? Is that process automatically done by python?